# How to do assign a type char a[] to an unsigned char b[]?

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass the `tempKey`(char array) to this function and want to assign it to `unsigned char key[]`. How would I go about doing this?

```
int do_crypt(FILE *in, FILE *out, char tempKey[21], char input_text[21])
{
    unsigned char key[16] = "";
    memcpy(key, tempKey, 16);
    unsigned char iv[] = "aabbccddeeff00998877665544332211";

    printf("%s", key);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int line_counter = 0;
    char *KeyFilename = NULL;
    char *InputFilename = NULL;

    char lines[MAX_LINE_NUM][MAX_LINE_LEN];
    char input_text[21];
    char tempKey[21];
    
    KeyFilename = argv[1];
    InputFilename = argv[2];

    read_KeyFile(&line_counter, KeyFilename, lines);
    getInputHexConverter(&line_counter, InputFilename, input_text);

    FILE *in;
    FILE *out;

    int k = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_LINE_NUM; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<MAX_LINE_LEN; j++){
            tempKey[k] = lines[i][j];
            // printf("%c", tempKey[k]);
            do_crypt(in, out, &tempKey[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `tempKey` is longer than 15 characters, `key` won't have a null terminator.

Comment: You're not calling `do_crypt()` with enough arguments.

Comment: Why don't you make `tempKey` unsigned as well?

Comment: Aside from the comments from @Barmar, what is wrong with what you have? What are you expecting, and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: Actually, even if `tempKey` is shorter it won't have a null terminator, since you never add it in `main()` before calling the function. You can't print an unterminated string using `%s`.